# Javascript - Changing string to match regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, format

I have a text area which I’m getting the value from and want to format this using a regex expression.My regex expression requires a number first space then characters then a multiline break.

```
This is my string = "282 MDJSL   889 MSHS 888 MSSH";
```

(This string could be random each time ).

So I want to turn this string this so its formated and eventurally put into a JSObject

```
282 MDJSL   
889 MSHS 
888 MSSH
```

This is my current code:

```
var textValue = $('#texbox2').val().toString();
var regex = new RegExp('/^[\s\S]*[\d\s]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[\n]+$/');
var str = textValue;
 if (regex.test(textValue) === true) {

  // Match found
  console.log('Regex match');

  if ((m = regex.exec(textValue)) !== null) {

   // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
   m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
      console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
   });

  }
 }

 // Match not found 
 else {
  // Not replacing it into the format i want
  str = str.replace(regex, str);
 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can get by with a simpler regex and code.

```js
var str = "282 MDJSL   889 MSHS 888 MSSH";

var regex = /\d+\s+[a-z]+/gi;
var m;
var i = 0;
while ((m = regex.exec(str))) {
  console.log(`Found match, group ${i++}: ${m}`);
}

if (i === 0) {
  // was no match
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could split by whitespace and a positive lookahead of a number.

```js
var string = "282 MDJSL \n\n  889 MSHS 888 MSSH",
    array = string.split(/\s+(?=\d)/);
    
console.log(array);
```